# Bind java client to a RabbitMQ exchange instead of a queue to consume all messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I know that in order to publish messages to RabbitMQ the client connects to an exchange. Is it possible to connect to the exchange instead of a queue in order to receive all the messages that this exchange will route afterwards? If it is possible, can you please provide me with the way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options.

One is to use the rabbitMQ firehose https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html. Which will copy all messages into an exchange.

Alternatively, you might be able to do this by writing a custom RabbitMQ plugin, so whatever you want to do, can happen inside RabbitMQ. I'm not familiar with this approach and it might mean having to compile a custom version of RabbitMQ. https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html